# activeMQ count matching message

Tags: activemq-classic

Hi guys,

I'm looking for a method to count a number of matching messages in ActiveMQ. Here is the code for adding a message:

```
ObjectMessage myBeanMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
myBeanMessage.setObject(myBean);
myBeanMessage.setStringProperty("myProperty", myBean.getProperty());
producer.send(myBeanMessage);
```

Now I want to count the number of message in myQueue whose myProperty = "a property String", for example, but do not found any QueueMBean api: 
http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.7.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/QueueViewMBean.html

The only api that maybe satisfy my requirement is

int copyMatchingMessagesTo(String selector, String destinationName)                    throws Exception

Copies the messages matching the given selector

Returns: the number of messages copied

Throws: Exception

which mean that I have to copy all matching messages to another queue and count the number of messages copied. 
However, I feel that to copy all matching message just to find how many messages are copied is somehow "unneccessary waste of resource".

So, is there any way that I can count the number of matching messages directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you can always browse the queue using that selector, and count the messages browsed. That means you will read the messages to a client, but not really copying them to another queue. If that is more performant/resource friendly in your scenario or worse, I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

The use case seems to tread into the realm of ActiveMQ (or JMS in general) [anti-patterns](http://sensatic.net/messaging/messaging-anti-patterns-part-1.html).

You need to remember that a Queue is not a database and treating it as such will, most likely end in tears.  In JMS you have the option of using a Queue Browser with selector to browse the Queue contents.  You must tread carefully there however as the spec only states that a browser will give you a snapshot of the Queue with no guarantee that you will browse all message.  In ActiveMQ when you browse a Queue you can only browse what will fit into memory and then the browse stops so your count could be way off for really deep Queues.